# google app engine -- Asynchronous blocks of code? python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, asynchronous

So I have some code that functions something like this generic code:

```
for blah in blahs:
   blah.take_forever()

for blah2 in blah2s:
  vars = blah2.take_forever()
  for var in vars:
     var.also_take_forever()
```

I want something that functions like async, such as

```
async_start_blah2_loop_then_do_someting_else()

do_the_first_blah_loop()

gather_results_and_send_them_out()
```

However, I'm not using the datastore or a urlfetch for this, so what other options will speed up this process?

"

```
map_async(callback, pass_batch_into_callback=None, merge_future=None, **q_options)
Asynchronously map a callback function or tasklet over the query results. This is the asynchronous version of map().
```

"

seems to only apply to datastore queries.

Suggestions?

Comment: Threading and/or async operations will only help when your waiting on some other service that takes time.  If it's all compute oriented then you won't gain anything.  One approach might  be to break up each the "take_for_ever" operation into separate discrete calls to appengine infrastructure. Let the front end make the requests and you might hit multiple instances

Comment: @Tim, yeah, I tried the threading, and it is due to another service taking time opposed to calculations (but not an app engine service). Right now angularjs is making an ajax post to my server which contains the code that takes a while. However, last night I was thinking I might try to use the queue service with angularjs and put the two functions on two different handlers so  that either function can come back with results when it's finished, instead of waiting on the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's native [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module in App Engine to execute functions asynchronously (see [threading.Thread](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread)). This also works fine on automatic scaled instances as it uses 'green' threads instead of OS threads.

```
def blahFunc():
  for blah in blahs:
    blah.take_forever()

def blah2Func():
  for blah2 in blah2s:
    vars = blah2.take_forever()
    for var in vars:
      var.also_take_forever()

# Execute both loops 'at the same time'
background = threading.Thread(target=blah2Func)
background.start() 
blah1Func()
```

Note that you won't necessarily gain any speed from this (I assume yours was a contrived example for simplicity) as the request still executes inside the same 'real' OS thread, but it is useful if you need to avoid blocking on a long operation.

If you have really long running tasks that may need to run longer than the request a better solution is to use [Task Queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/).

Comment: The blah code is inside a def post(self).. I need the response to the post function to be fed back to the angularjs which did an ajax call to the post in order to modify the $scope variables... don't I?  I'm not quite sure how that would work if I use a task queue. I'm new to angularjs. Is that possible? After all that confusing wording, what I mean is, is it possible to use a task queue to update $scope variables on an html page?

Comment: so I tried the thread. You're right, assuming that I had to call background.join(), it took about the same amount of time, as the first function is fast, the second one is slow.

Comment: In your case since you are relying on the results client-side, making things async on the backend won't provide any net benefit (so task queues would be out as well). The async part should be happening client-side in the form of the ajax call. If you are blocking on the results of the ajax call this would be a time to reconsider your design since that defeats the point of the 'asynchronous' in ajax.

Comment: :) I believe we're already on the same page-- that's what my comment to tim above was regarding